# eDiscovery cases in the Office 365 Security & Compliance Center not restricting content from deletion SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, ediscovery

I have created a new eDiscovery cases in the Office 365 Security & Compliance Center and added one of my SharePoint online site as a place to put on the hold. I've just added the site, no additional filters etc. Then, I've waited for a day to let the hold take place. Went to SharePoint Admit center and saw that the site is showing with a lock icon, which tells me that the site can't be deleted due to a hold, but, I was still able to delete contents from the site. I was wondering if anyone can tell me if I am doing something wrong or if my expectation is somehow not correct.

[image: SharePoint Admin center showing hold]

[image: Hold showing SharePoint site]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When an item under retention policy or legal hold is deleted a copy of that file is stored in preservation and hold library. This is a hidden library managed by Office 365. You can access it at /sites/sitename/PreservationHoldLibrary.

You can read more about it on microsoft docs [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/securitycompliance/retention-policies)

Comment: Thanks! As per Step 4 on this Microsoft Document [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/Office365/SecurityCompliance/ediscovery-cases?redirectSourcePath=%252fen-us%252farticle%252fmanage-ediscovery-cases-in-the-security--compliance-center-9a00b9ea-33fd-4772-8ea6-9d3c65e829e6) _italic_When you place content locations on hold, content is held until you remove the hold from the content location or until you delete the hold._italic_ , is not correct then?

Comment: It is correct, the content is not really deleted but held (in preservation library if deleted by user) until the hold is removed or deleted. When you try to view the document in the eDiscovery search page, you can still find, view and export the document as Office 365 still holds the document in preservation library even though the user deleted it.